# Hive - insert values in array from file (comma and semicolon separated)

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive

I have a file with columns separated by semicolons. I want to add a `type` column as an `Array<String>`. What I have now is that I store my values raw, just like this (the `type` column is text):

```
|  age  |  type  |  country  |
     24      a          us
     29      a,b        au         <--------- this line is not OK
     25      a          uk
```

My file is like the following:

```
age;type1,type2;country
age;type1;country
age;type2;country
```

How do I correctly put the types in my table as an `Array<String>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same data will work. Create table :

```
CREATE TABLE array_data_type(
  age int,
  type array<string>,
  contry varchar(100))
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' 
  COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Load same data in this table.

If this data is in a local file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '<file-path>' INTO TABLE array_data_type;
```

or in case of HDFS file:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '<hdfs-file-path>' INTO TABLE array_data_type;
```

Comment: Great. But what if there's comma in my country but I don't want to store it as an array? Will it there be an error or something? Thanks!

Comment: @r3v0lt country is not of array type. So there will not be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I have the following error: FAILED: ParseException line 8:22 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting StringLiteral near 'BY' in table row format's field separator. Any hint?

Comment: Ok got it. I remember that `;` OCT code is 073. So I replaced `';'` by `'\073'`. Thanks!

Comment: @r3v0lt I updated the answer for future user references

Comment: @r3v0lt `;` is line terminator in hive `\;` should also work.